# Why do all multiples of 99 have a digit sum $\geq 18$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I noticed that this seems to be the case while looking at some multiples.

**Q: Can someone come up with a positive conterexample or show that there can't be one?**

Comment: On every natural base $B$, every multiple of $B-1$ has a digit-sum of $B-1$. So, for example, if we were counting on base $8$, it would be easy for us to determine (without a calculator) whether a number is divisible by $7$ or not.

Comment: See also [Multiples of $999$ have digit sum $\geq 27$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2869135/242). $\ \ $

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint: The sum of the digits must be a multiple of $9$. The alternating sum of the digits must be divisible by $11$. If the alternating sum is non-zero, then the sum must be greater than $11$, and thus at least $18$...

If the alternating sum is $0$, then can the sum be $9$?

Answer (score 0):

Because in base 10, nonzero multiples of 9 have to have a digit sum that is a multiple of 9, and multiples of 11 must have an alternating sum of digits equal to a multiple of 11. These two things I've just mentioned are well-accepted facts and it sounds like you've done plenty of verification with individual examples.

Let's call $s_1$ the sum of the odd-place digits and $s_2$ the sum of the even-place digits. You're looking to solve $s_1 + s_2 = 9$ and $s_1 - s_2 = 11m$ simultaneously, where $m$ is some integer. That is the only constraint on $m$. And either $s_1$ or $s_2$ may be 0 (not both), but neither may be negative. Furthermore, $s_1 \leq 9$, and likewise for $s_2$. With these constraints, the two equations have no common solution, and therefore no counterexample can exist.

Comment: Thank you - that's really intelligible! but I am a little confused with: $s_1 + s_2 = 9$ don't you mean $9n$? because the sum of odd- and even-placed digits has to be a multiple of 9?

Comment: If, for example, $s_1 + s_2 = 27$ the number is a multiple of 9 but the digit sum is more than 18, but you're looking for a digit sum less than 18, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: oh of course! :) my fault. sorry.